# ASP.NET MVC default Identity Model merging with own entity framework code first mssql database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I looked at an article about extending the default asp.net mvc 5 Identity Model for register and login [here](http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2013/10/27/Configuring-Db-Connection-and-Code-First-Migration-for-Identity-Accounts-in-ASPNET-MVC-5-and-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx)

My question is, how can I merge the default login system with my own entity framework code first database with the ability to extend the login system too, should I use two different databases for login and other functions? It seems the whole thing about extending the asp.net mvc 5 login system with own database is very complicated even though most of the articles I see suggest otherwise...there is just not enough documentation and implementing a complete new login system is not a solution for me because there's security concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look for examples of using ASP.NET Identity without using the Entity Framework for example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961

This will show you how to use the basic authentication, where you can plugin your own validation to your own database.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, although this is not exactly what i want, but hey the answer is only as good as the question.